# How to execute the Maven Integration-Test Lifecyle phase twice

Tags: java, maven, integration-testing

I want to execute the complete Maven Integration-Test Lifecyle (`pre-integration-test`, `integration-test`, `post-integration-test`) twice.

I use the `cargo-maven2-plugin` to start a tomcat in `pre-integration-test` phase and shut it down in `post-integration-test`. In between (in `integration-test`) I use `maven-failsafe-plugin` to run the integration test.

The problem is that I have two different server configurations (that can be tested with the same integration test). And I need to test them both. But I do not have the resource to run both servers in parallel. So I need to repeat the complete integration test twice:

- `pre-integration-test (1)`
- `integration-test (1)`
- `post-integration-test (1)`
- `pre-integration-test (2)`
- `integration-test (2)`
- `post-integration-test (2)`

Does anybody has an idea how to modify the maven lifecyle in this way?

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution make two separate modules which contain the configuration for the integration tests and that should do the trick.

Comment: I still have trouble to imagine how this should work. (At the moment it is a simple-one-module maven project) I need to split it in a multi module project with: 4 modules:war, integrationtest-code, integration-test-execution1 and integration-test-execution2. -- Is this what you suggested?